# What's the relevance of the Note in [over.load]/1?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, using-directives, using-declaration

(You might see this question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042197/whats-the-meaning-of-the-highlighted-sentence-below-in-over-load-1), but, to be honest, I've not really understood the matter, so I'm asking separately with my own wording.)

[[over.load]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over#load-1) reads:

> Not all function declarations can be overloaded. Those that cannot be overloaded are specified here. A program is ill-formed if it contains two such non-overloadable declarations in the same scope. [ *Note:* This restriction applies to explicit declarations in a scope, and between such declarations and declarations made through a *using-declaration*. It does not apply to sets of functions fabricated as a result of name lookup (e.g., because of *using-directives*) or overload resolution (e.g., for operator functions). — *end note*]

As a provisional question, am I correct to say that *"This restriction"* refers to the fact that *"Not all function declarations can be overloaded"*?

If that's the case, then I would deduce that if I create the situation that a set *"of functions fabricated as a result of name lookup"* exists, then those ***can be overloaded even if they are specified there*** in the list following the quoted paragraph above, because the restriction does not apply.

But what does that even mean, and how is it useful to know it?

I very well know that I can't overload function differing only in the return type, as this erroneous code demonstrates,

```cpp
int f() { return 1; };
double f() { return 2; }; // compile-time error
```

and I also know that the same identical scenario happens if one of the two `f`s is in another namespace but brought in via `using` declaration

```cpp
int f() { return 1; };
namespace n {
double f() { return 2; };
}
using n::f; // compile-time error
```

I think the first snippet above is an example of *explicit declarations in a scope*, whereas the second snippet is an example of *between such declarations and declarations made through a `using`-declaration*.

But what is an example *of functions fabricated as a result of name lookup (e.g., because of using-directives)*? Something like this?

```cpp
int f() { return 1; };
namespace n {
double f() { return 2; };
}
using namespace n; // no error, as n::f can be seen by name lookup, but it's not actually declared here
```

If that's the case, what should I deduce from it? The restriction does not apply, so I can overload this 2 functions. What does it mean? Am I already overloading them as soon as I write the 5-lines snippet above? Or do I need to make a call such as `auto x = f()`? In that case, the call is ambiguous, though.

I really don't understand what that *Note* is trying to tell.

Comment: _Am I already overloading them as soon as I write the 5-lines snippet above?_ It does not match the definition of overloading. _I really don't understand what that Note is trying to tell_ That lookup can produce an overload set with functions as-if they were illegally overloaded in the scope of the lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example with the *using-directive*, the functions are not overloaded. Overloading is defined in [over.pre]/1:

> When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said to be *overloaded*, and the declarations are called *overloaded declarations*. ...

The two `f`'s are not in the same scope, so they are not overloaded.

However, if you attempt to call `f`, an *overload set* will be formed from the result of name lookup, and it contains both `f` declarations. An *overload set* is always fabricated; it is created when the name is *used* (not just declared); such fabrication can potentially bring multiple functions into the same overload set despite the fact that it would have been illegal to overload those functions with each other. The note is pointing out that it is not ill-formed to create such an overload set.

Of course, overload resolution might be ambiguous, leading to an ill-formed program, but there are ways of using the overload set that are well-formed. For example, the following is A-OK:

```
int f() { return 1; };
namespace n {
double f() { return 2; };
}
using namespace n;
double (*fp)() = &f;
```

Comment: _overload resolution might be ambiguous, leading to an ill-formed program, but it might also not be ambiguous. For example_ seems to say that overload resolution is not ambiguous in the snippet you show. But where does it happen at all, if there's no function call?

Comment: @Enlico overload resolution is done when taking the address of an overload set. 
Although, now that I look at it again, I suppose it might not technically be overload resolution. https://eel.is/c++draft/over.over